# What is the difference between matter and substance?

Tags: meaning

I cannot fully understand about the difference between matter and substance? In other questions I found question about the difference between material and substance, but I do not know about matter. Does matter include substances? 
Help me please.

Comment: You say *matter*, I think physics. You say *substance*, I think chemistry.

Comment: The terminology and the main distinction come from Aristotle; there are many metaphorical senses now in everyday use, which extend the primary meanings. I don't have time right now to explain them well today. My answer [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/51939/6700) briefly explains the primary sense of "matter". [This article](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/substance/) gives a very long explanation of the primary senses of "substance" (probably more than you want to know), with some hints about the extended, everyday senses.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about physics or chemistry not language. They can give a much better answer.

Comment: All matter that exists in the universe is made of atoms. Water is matter because it's made of atoms: one oxygen atom and two hydrogen atoms. Nitric acid is also matter because it's made of atoms as well: one hydrogen atom, one nitrogen atom and three oxygen atoms. But water and nitric acid are different kinds of substances because their molecules are different. Very broadly speaking, all matter in the universe is represented by different substances.

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot of overlap, but "matter" and "substance" are not interchangeable in all circumstances.

In physics, "matter" means everything in the universe except energy (and of course, by Einstein's famous formula, matter can be converted into energy!)
Anything that can be seen is matter; and physicists also posit the existence of "dark matter", which cannot be seen.

In ordinary conversation, a "matter" can be an issue of discussion. Or a "private matter" (not for discussion).

- "Matter" might be some particular type of material such as  "printed matter".
- Or it can mean a problem, as in "What's the matter with you?"
- "Gray matter" is your brain.

Aside: "Material", as a noun, usually refers to what something is made of, in particular (such as types of cloth, or metals such as steel, etc.; or as a class, such as "building materials".)  As an adjective, it is similar to "relevant",  as in "material evidence". Likewise, "immaterial" means irrelevant.

"Substance" is typically used for

- more elemental or unrefined matter than "material" is used for (such as dirt or clay);
- something unidentified/ unnamed, as "a black, gooey substance".
- (figuratively) importance—"a man of substance".

"Substantial" means large or numerous. "Insubstantial" means lightweight or flimsy, as an argument.

You can say "the substance of the matter" (meaning the crux/gist of an issue), but you probably would not say "the matter of the substance".

Comment: @RabinRabinhood This answer is very good (I gave it a +1 myself), but in my opinion not perfect. No explanation of the meanings of "matter" vs "substance" could ever be perfect! Some crucial stuff is missing, like an explanation of why "substantive" is a synonym for "noun". Keep searching. Damkerng's comment on your question provides another important clue. If you have access to the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/193042), that's a great source.

Answer (score 0):

Cambridge Dictionary Online suggests these meanings:

> Substance - material with particular physical characteristics, e. g. What sort of substance could withstand those temperatures?
>
> Matter - physical substance in the universe, e. g. Some scientists believe that there is about ten times as much matter in the universe as astronomers have observed.
>
> Matter -  a substance of a particular kind, e. g. Most vegetable matter is compostable.

So, you see that **matter** is a **substance** of a particular kind.

Answer (score 0):

We can say that substance is a matter but we can say that matter is a substance. Anything that occupies space and has mass is matter but the matter that has specific composition and chemical characteristics is substance. like elements. Examples: solid, liquid and gases, sodium, mercury and oxygen.

Comment: I think there should be a *cannot* instead of *can* in your first sentence.

Answer (score -1):

Element and compound is called a substance. All the atoms in an element are similar. In a compound all the molecules are identical. It means the word substance is used for pure matter.